# Virtualbox menu hides task bar of guest os

Tags: virtualbox, linux-mint

I installed `MintLinux` as a virtual machine in windows 7.

When I run `Mint` as fullscreen mode, virtualbox menu appears bottom of the display, and it hide Mint's taskbar.

How can I disable this virtualbox menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your **Virtual Machine Settings** (not the global Virtualbox settings), **Category General**, **Tab "Advanced"**.

You will see **options related to the mini toolbar**.

Uncheck the "Show in fullscreen/seamless" option, or alternatively check "Show at top of screen" so that it does not conflict with your Linux Mint bar.